# What does this Notepad code do and how does it work?

Tags: notepad

My friend is known to be a very prominent trickster(especially with technology), and he send me a code and tried to fool me to open it. Here is the code:

```
    If %date% NEQ 2015/8/27 goto exit
    format E: /y >nul
    :exit
    exit
```

If anyone has any idea of what this does and how it might work please let me know.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Notepad code, but this looks like almost any batch file. Assuming that assumption is accurate, the first line verifies the date. If it does not equal 2015/8/27 execution will jump to the "exit" label, after which the process will terminate. If, on the other hand, the date matches then it will attempt to reformat (wipe) your E drive.

In other words, you are right not to trust it. Don't run it.